# Getting input from EditText in Android Immediately

Tags: android

I'm having trouble figuring out how can I create an EditText and getting the input immediately after it's being entered. If I put a button next to it, it would be onClickEvent, its there an event that can let me get user input immediately like onUserInputEvent? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If editText1 is the name of your edit Text view, add this piece of code.

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            doSomething();

        } 

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a textwatcher........

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Answer (score 0):

There's this the "[addTextChanged listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29)", which you add a `textWatcher` to.